# How do I set up a menu for my application?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, menu

I am making an application with multiple options, but am unclear as how to go about setting up a menu that is activated within my main activity, and then returning to the main activity after used.
I have looked up various tutorials but still am a bit confused.
Help? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create each menu item as an activity then use this code. Note you will also have to create an xml file for the menu as per http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

```
//Methods for menu
// display the menu when menu botton clicked

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lightmeter, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.about).setIntent(new Intent(this, about.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.edit).setIntent(new Intent(this, menu.class));
    return true;
}

//methods for menu
//StartActivity for selecion

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
startActivity(item.getIntent());
return true;
}
```